# Plugin menu replaced by another plugin?

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin-menu

Sorry if my title is not clear as i'm not sure what i'm asking. Haven't seen this issue in my searches on the stack-exchange sites. Note I am not the author of either plugin.

So the issue I am having is that I had a plugin, activating the plugin put that plugins icon/menus directly underneath the POST tab/menus in the left hand navigation in admin which is fine.

The issue is that i installed another plugin, which once activated is put right under the posts tab "overwrites" the tab location on the left hand navigation, and thus there is no more icon/menu from the previous plugin. It's as if they both are dedicated to the same array location.

Is there a way to fix this situation?

Comment: What are the two plugins?

Comment: @AndrewBartel Newscred and Wordpress auto spinner. Basically we have a content contract through newscred who posts their own plugin to work with their special RSS (sigh), and are looking to spin some of the content for uniqueness using spinner. wordpress auto spinner is a paid plugin.

Comment: So, I would guess that one of them is explicitly remove the menu item by the other one.  Even if the position got overwritten, it should still just push it down.  I would ask the plugin authors.  That, or they may somehow have the same menu slug.

Comment: the plugin author(s) will likely have to fix this. from `add_menu_page`: *WARNING: if two menu items use the same position attribute, one of the items may be overwritten so that only one item displays! Risk of conflict can be reduced by using decimal instead of integer values, e.g. 63.3 instead of 63 (Note: Use quotes in code, IE '63.3')*.

Comment: I have written to the wordpress authors as part of due diligence, but is there a way i can change this on my end?